# Can I set a different property at the end of a Storyboard/Animation in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I want to make an image flash a set number of times, when I set its Visibility to Visible.  And when it's finished flashing, I want it to make itself Collapsed again.

Here's a simple version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<Image Visibility="Collapsed"
       Margin="0,0,3,0"
       Width="24"
       Source="blah"
       Height="24">
  <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility"
                  Value="Visible">
          <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="5x"
                          x:Name="flashingStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                                FillBehavior="Stop">
                  <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0"
                                          KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                  <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="1"
                                          KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Can I do this in XAML?

Answer (score 5):

If you know how many times it will be flashed then you can set BeginTime correspondingly the number of times your flashing comes along.

```
<BeginStoryboard>
       <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="5x" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1">
              <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
              <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

Comment: Your solution didn't quite work for me because of the RepeatBehavior, I think.  I've added what I came up with based on yours.

Comment: Your solution brings the same results. I checked my code and it works.